# Determining if a point is "trapped" (enclosed) on a grid

Tags: arrays, path-finding

I have a grid (example below) containing outside walls (marked as W), environment blocks (E), open space (o) and active points (A). Presently, this grid is stored in a [,] with all of the data associated with a given point. I'm trying to determine if an active point is enclosed (defined as being incapable of reaching the top of the grid because it's blocked by environment blocks), but I'm having difficulty finding a simple way of solving this problem. I know that I could implement A* and it would be more-or-less easy with all the sample code out there, but I don't think the performance hit would really be necessary or worth it for such a seemingly trivial operation.

```
W--Top Of Grid--W
W---------------W
W-EEAEE-----EEE-W
WEEEEEEE-EEEEAEEW
WEEEEEEE--EEEEEEW
WEEEEEEEE-AEEEEEW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

The A on the third line down can draw a path to the top of the grid, as can the one on the last line, however the one on the fourth line down cannot. I don't care for the actual paths, I just need to determine if the object is trapped or not. What would be the optimal solution to this project?

For what it's worth, it's a C# project for a turn-based grid game if that helps at all.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer, it's much appreciated.

Comment: If the grid is anywhere near that small, the "performance hit" will be near-nothing, so go ahead and implement A*.  You could also do a simple breadth-first search, but A* is really not any more complicated than BFS.

Comment: The grid is significantly larger (can be as high as 100x100 nodes), the one shown is small for ease of viewing. Would that still apply on that scale?

Comment: I would still say that probably won't be a problem, unless you also have a lot of "active points".  Just set the heuristic to the height from the top.  When it's all done, profile your application, and see if the pathfinding is a bottleneck - if so, maybe we can come up with something faster, but until then, it's not worth your time trying to optimize it.

Answer (score 2):

I think a floodfill from the top grids will solve all the problem. Flood from the top, then check which 'A' are flooded :)

The algorithm guarantees to visit each node only once during the whole process, which can not be faster in worst case. And it's really easy to be implemented in any language.

Here's the algorithm from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill):

```
 Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 2. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 3. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 4. Return.
```

...and it looks like: (from wiki)

[image: Flood fill]

In short:

1. flood from the top grids, with 'W' and 'E' blocking the flood (like the black cells in the picture)
2. after the flood, check how many places containing 'A' are flooded.

Comment: This would be even worse than BFS, unless there are many "active nodes."  A* would definitely be preferable for a large grid.